# How to make a splash screen involving 3D objects?

Tags: android, animation, 3d

My main View has a dark background and I want to overlay a 3D obj file that looks like the picture below . Is it possible to do this? and how can I do it

[image: 3D earth particles]

PS: I dont want to use it as GIF since I want to overlay the 3D animation on my view